# Laravel: My method is not returning curl result, returns pased parameters instead

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel app I use curl to send notifications via FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) rest API using curl and php, when I execute curl I save result to result variable along with http code and return it, however what I receive in $notification variable is the parametters passed to NewMatchMotif instead of curl result:

```
$notification = new NewMatchNotif($user, $data, 'es');
```

Something like this:

```
{user: {…}, data: {…}, locale: "es"}
```

My NewMatch Notification:

```
<?php
namespace App\Notifications;

use App\Helpers\CloudMessaging;
use Lang;
use Log;

class NewMatchNotif
{
    
    public $user;
    public $data;
    public $locale;

    public function __construct($user, $data, $locale)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->locale = $locale;
        $this->load();
    }

    public function load()
    {
        $cloudMessaging = new CloudMessaging();
        $result = $cloudMessaging->send($this->user, 'title', 'body', $this->data, 'NewMatchNotif');
        return $result;
    }
    

}
```

My send method

```
public function send($user,$title,$body, $data = false , $type, $image='')
    { 
        $fields = '...';
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
        $fields = json_encode($fields);
    
        $headers = 
        [
            'Authorization: key='. config('services.firebase.api_key'),
            'Content-Type: application/json',
        ];  

        $ch = curl_init ();
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY  , true); 
    
        $result = curl_exec ( $ch );
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        curl_close ( $ch );

        $output = 
        [
            'httpCode' => $httpcode,
            'result' => $result
        ];
        
        return $output;
    }
```

What is going on, this part is pretty straight fordward yet I'm not getting the desired results:

```
 $result = curl_exec ( $ch );
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        curl_close ( $ch );

        $output = 
        [
            'httpCode' => $httpcode,
            'result' => $result
        ];
        
        return $output;
```

Comment: A constructor returns the object being constructed, nothing else. Even if it were possible to return something else, you're not trying to. You can do as the answer below suggests, or simply `$notification = (new NewMatchNotif($user, $data, 'es'))->load();`

Comment: Also note that Laravel has a built-in HTTP client, there's no need to do the curl nonsense. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the result after instanciate the class, like:

```
<?php
namespace App\Notifications;

use App\Helpers\CloudMessaging;
use Lang;
use Log;

class NewMatchNotif
{
    
    public $user;
    public $data;
    public $locale;
    public $result;

    public function __construct($user, $data, $locale)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->locale = $locale;
        $this->load();
    }

    private function load()
    {
        $cloudMessaging = new CloudMessaging();
        $this->result = $cloudMessaging->send($this->user, 'title', 'body', $this->data, 'NewMatchNotif');
    }
    

}
```

And then:

```
$notification = (new NewMatchNotif($user, $data, 'es'))->result;
```